# Running custom javascript function in Selenium IDE and storing value

Tags: selenium-ide

I would like to run the below snipped in Selenium IDE and store the value  O can use it. I have some varialbles already stored as in below to be inserted into function. I have tried but when I echo it does not return anything. Here is screenshot attached

```
function Generate(){
var luhnSum = 0;
        for( var x=0; x<10; x++ ) {
    var product = multipliers[x] * parseInt(luhnBase.charAt(x), 10);
        if( product < 10 ) {
            luhnSum += product;
        } else {
            luhnSum += (product-10)+1;
        }
    } 
    var checkDigit = luhnSum % 10; 
    return ${alphaChar} + ${random8} + checkDigit.toString();
}
```

I am hoping to get a screenshot of exaclty how I would run this to ensure I am doing it correctly